# Firebase is not defined when connecting to Realtime Database Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uncaught-reference-error

I am trying to connect my Realtime Firebase Database to my Web App and eventually store data in it.

I keep running into the same problem when loading my HTML file. The error I get in the console is `Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`.

This is what my script looks like:

```js
<script type="module">

      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js";
      import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-analytics.js";

      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "<api key>",
        authDomain: "<domain>",
        databaseURL: "<db url>",
        projectId: "<project id>",
        storageBucket: "<bucket>",
        messagingSenderId: "<id>",
        appId: "<app id>",
        measurementId: "<id>"
      };

      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

      var database = firebase.database();
      var postListRef = database.ref('posts');
      var newPostRef = postListRef.push();
      newPostRef.set({
        "post1": "testing"
      });

</script>
```

Comment: You are calling `firebase.database()` but where is it ? :D

Comment: @Kid I have tried importing `getDatabase` but that didn't help. Is there another script tag I should add?

Comment: Instead of importing initializeApp and getAnalytics one by one, try to import the whole module. `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>`

Comment: also, there's `firebase-database.js` as well

Comment: @Kid I added the script tag to the head and removed the imports and now I also received `initializeApp` is not defined, either.

Comment: @Kid I believe the above error was caused by two other errors. One from `firebase-app.js`: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`. And the other from `firebase-database.js`: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing functions from Firebase using new v9 modular SDK syntax. In that syntax you have top-level functions like `getDatabase()`, instead of objects like `firebase.database()`.

The equivalent of the Realtime Database code in your snippet is:

```
var database = getDatabase(app);
var postListRef = ref(database, 'posts');
var newPostRef = push(postListRef);
set(newPostRef, {
  "post1": "testing"
});
```

I recommend keeping the Firebase documentation on [reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), [appending data to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), and the [modular upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) handy.

---

If you have a lot of existing Realtime Database code, you can migrate in steps by [importing the `compat` path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) first:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/database';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For importing, when I import inside the script tag, it only works with the URLs. To add things like getDatabase, ref, and push, what should I import?

Comment: Ah, never mind. I imported them all through what Kid suggested above. The code works now. Thanks again! :)

Comment: D. didn't try 9.0 so my bad