# Why am i getting initializeApp is not defined in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, module, firebase-authentication, uncaught-reference-error

My JS code(I am using the browser's window object than modules for now):

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script>
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
       //My app config
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
      const auth = firebaseApp.auth();
    </script>
```

But I get this error:   initializeApp is not defined

Comment: You are mixing APIs between the legacy namespaced SDK (v8 and older) and the modern modular SDK (v9+). See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) on how to spot it and use the new syntax. [This question has more information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69230383/3068190) related to your issue.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70308933/firebase-js12-uncaught-referenceerror-initializeapp-is-not-defined (and the documentation and upgrade guide I linked from there), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104981/firebase-is-not-defined-when-connecting-to-realtime-database-web, and many more of the links you get when [searching for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bfirebase%5d%20initializeApp%20is%20not%20defined).